Looking for a doc explaining when the .mod is generated or not with gfortran compiler?
A file (my_module.f90) containing a module is compiled with gfortran -c my_module.f90.
If this file is edited, there are two cases :

If prototypes of subroutines and functions are not changed, only
my_module.o is generated.
If prototypes of subroutines and functions are changed,
my_module.mod and my_module.o are generated.

This is very convenient to avoid recompiling all files that use this module.
But, I am not able to find a doc explaining how gfortran compiler distinguishes these two cases. Could you give me some clues to understand ? Thanks for answer.
 EDIT 1 
I wrote it is convenient because in a makefile (see below), the files that depend of the module are not compiled again. Only the end linking is done.
.SUFFIXES:

FC=gfortran
LD=gfortran

F90MODSRC = my_module.f90
F90SRC = main.f90

F90OBJ = $(F90MODSRC:%.f90=%.o) $(F90SRC:%.f90=%.o)
F90MOD = $(F90MODSRC:%.f90=%.mod)

my_pgm : $(F90OBJ)
    $(LD) -o $@ $+

$(F90MOD):%.mod: %.f90
    
$(F90OBJ): %.o: %.f90
    $(FC) -c $<

main.o: my_module.mod

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -rm -f $(F90OBJ) $(F90MOD) my_pgm


I doubt there is any formal doccument for that. I would be frankly quite surprised if there was one.

There is at least one other case.  If the namespace changes, the *.mod will be updated.  If you compile this, module foo ; integer x; end module foo, you get foo.mod.  Now, edit the file to have integer x, y and recompile.  You get a new foo.mod file.

I wonder if a temporary .mod is generated and if there is no difference with the existing one, the .mod is not outputted. I use only gfortran. Is it the same behaviour with others compilers ?

The answer you seek is in the source code.  Search for CRC32.

@steve. Thanks for this answer. I found it after the comment Read the CRC32 from the gzip trailers of the module files and compare.
